# Using Marshaling and a BinaryReader to parse a file that defines its own structure

Tags: c#, marshalling, binaryreader

I am working on reading a binary file that is comprised of numerous data block, each defined by a struct. Each block begins with a unique signature to indicate what kind of data is to be read, and which I can also use to determine the length of the block to read.

I would like to be able to read the signature, already done, and then rewind the binary reader by the size of the signature before Marshaling the file data into the appropriate structure.

Is it possible to rewind a BinaryReader by x bytes?

*Edit: changed the handle type to Pinned*

My code thus far is:

```
private bool parseFile( string fName, string fPath )
{
    using ( FileStream elFile = File.OpenRead( fPath + "\\" + fName ) )
    {
        using ( BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader( elFile ) )
        {
            int sigSize = sizeof( RtdSigs );
            byte[] readBuff = new byte[ sigSize ];

            readBuff = bReader.ReadBytes( sigSize );

            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc( readBuff, GCHandleType.Pinned );
            RtdSigs sig = (RtdSigs)Marshal.PtrToStructure( handle.AddrOfPinnedObject( ), typeof( RtdSigs ) );

            switch ( sig )
            {
            case RtdSigs.RTD_FileHeader_SIG:

                break;
            case RtdSigs.RTD_Readings_SIG:

                break;
            case RtdSigs.RTD_Status_SIG:

                break;
            case RtdSigs.RTD_Parameter_SIG:

                break;

            default:

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum QtcRtdSigs : ulong
{
    RTD_Readings_SIG = 0x8b001001,
    RTD_Status_SIG = 0x88001002,
    RTD_FileHeader_SIG = 0x83001009,
    RTF_Parameter_SIG = 0x8d001007,
}

#region blockTypes
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct RtdReadings
{
    public QtcRtdSigs sig;
    public UInt32 instanceId;
    public UInt16 dataType;
    public UInt16 readingCount;
    public UInt32 mileage;
    public UInt32 flags;
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1 )]
public struct RtdFileHeader
{
    public QtcRtdSigs sig;
    public UInt64 dateTime;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=33)]
    public string project;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33 )]
    public string isiName;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33 )]
    public string appName;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33 )]
    public string role;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33 )]
    public string comment;

    public UInt32 carId;
    public UInt32 trainId;
    public UInt32 cfgDbRev;
    public UInt32 cfgDbSerial;
    public UInt32 flags;
    public UInt32 reserved2;
    public UInt32 reserved3;
    public UInt32 reserved4;
    public UInt32 reserved5;
    public UInt32 reserved6;
    public UInt32 reserved7;
    public UInt32 reserved8;
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct RtdStatus
{
    public QtcRtdSigs sig;
    public UInt64 dateTime;
    public UInt32 bitFields;
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct RtdParameter
{
    public QtcRtdSigs sig;
    public UInt64 dateTime;
    public UInt32 bitFields;
    public UInt32 value;
    public UInt32 prevValue;
}
#endregion
```

The overall structure of the file can be demonstrated using the block types as:

```
RtdFileHeader  
RtdReadings - specifies type of the next reading and the number of readings    
RtdStatus    
RtdStatus    
RtdReadings    
RtdParameter    
RtdParameter    
RtdParameter   
RtdReadings    
RtdStatus
```

etc.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, BinaryReader only reads what it needs from the base stream and doesn't buffer anything more.  Use elFile.Seek().

Comment: I didn't know you could use GCHandleType.Normal together with AddrOfPinnedObject. That's unsafe since Normal doesn't pin. The pointer can become invalid any time.

Comment: I assumed it would be safe in this case as the only time I need the handle is in the next line.
Perhaps this is an unsafe assumption and I should switch it to GCHandleType.Pinned

Comment: Hmm, that cannot work.  Code bombs with InvalidOperationException, "Handle is not pinned".

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code.  Now to figure out a use case for when GCHandleType.Normal is used.